# Ffmpeg output stream closed

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, nestjs

There is one problem in my code that uses ffmpeg to convert webm videos to mp4 and set duration to 10 seconds, it works well but, sometimes returns "output Stream closed" error. What can be a reason of this problem, and how can i solve it?

My code:

```
async convertWebmVideoToMp4(buffer: any) {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const videoMp4Buffer = Buffer.from(buffer);

            const readable = Readable.from(videoMp4Buffer);

            const outputBuffer = [];

            const outputStream = new Writable({
                write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                    outputBuffer.push(chunk);
                    callback();
                },
            });

            const ffmpegProcess = ffmpeg()
                .input(readable)
                .outputFormat('mp4')
                .videoCodec('libx264')
                .audioCodec('aac')
                .duration(10)
                .outputOptions([
                    '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
                    '-preset ultrafast',
                    '-c:a aac',
                    '-r 30',
                    '-tune fastdecode',
                ])
                .on('end', () => {
                    outputStream.end();
                    const finalOutputBuffer = Buffer.concat(outputBuffer);
                    resolve(finalOutputBuffer);
                })
                .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                });

            outputStream.on('error', err => {
                this.logger.error(err);
            });

            ffmpegProcess.pipe(outputStream, { end: true });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

My code should return the buffer of video that type is mp4 and length is 10 seconds, but it returns "output stream closed" error.